# Use Join In Delete Zend 2

Tags: zend-framework2, left-join

How can I use join in zend 2 delete query?
For example :

> DELETE t1 FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.id WHERE t2.id IS NULL;

I won't write query directly.

```
    $Delete = new Delete();
    $Delete->from("example");
    $Delete->join // join is not available
```

Comment: problem is using zend 2 classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears you are using `Zend\Db\Sql\Delete`. There is no method join for this class according to the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html#zend-db-sql-delete).

It appears it is not the "zend way" to delete multiple row from multiple table at once.
You could either

- Delete the rows with multiple query (one for each table)
- Make your own query using the dbAdapter provided by zend

hope this will help you